# factory_girl: Factories fails validation(of time) on create, but in my app, the validation passes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have created an application with a strict input validation for time.. You have to type in the time with this format: **14:00**.

This works fine, but when i create Factories with factory-girl, for my tests, the validation fails and i can see that factory-girl tries to create them with this data: **2000-01-01 14:00:00 UTC**

This is my factory:

```
factory :stamp do
  end_time "14:00"
end
```

So when i run **FactoryGirl.create(:stamp)** FG tries to set **end_time** to: **2000-01-01 14:00:00 UTC**, and my validation fails.

This is my validation method:

```
validates :start_time, :end_time, :format => { :with => /[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]/,
                                   :message => "You have to enter a time in this format 14:00"
```

How can i make FactoryGirl  create the models without tampering with the time-data and fail validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to force the FactoryGirl format for end_time:

```
factory :stamp do
  end_time Time.new(2013,1,1,14,0,0).strftime("%H:%M")
end
```

`strftime("%H:%M")` converts the time to the format you are looking for

Comment: This is also useful if you are putting a string into your web form for integration testing.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your output, end_time is a Time type, so it is going to automatically cast from String to Time. You should not be doing a string format validation on a non-String datatype (it is always going to be stored internally as `2000-01-01 14:00:00 UTC`).

If you want to validate input format, I would recommend doing this at the View/Controller level, and validate the presence of `start_time` and `end_time` on the Model. ActiveRecord will throw an error on create or save if the format is not able to be cast to a Time properly.

Comment: Thank you for the input. It sounds reasonable. I have never created validations on the controller/view layer before though.

Comment: At my company, we generally validate on the View level and the Model level. View level with some sort of JavaScript to ensure things like input formatting. On the model level, presence, uniqueness, etc.